# Iterating through the files in a folder (C++)

Tags: c++, file, loops, directory

I'm trying to search through all of the files in a folder on my computer. A lot of sources recommend using Boost, but I've been told that the following code could work.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA currentFile;

HANDLE searchHandle = FindFirstFile("C:\\MyFolder\\", &currentFile);

do
{
    /*Do something each time it finds a file*/
} while (FindNextFile(searchHandle, &currentFile));
```

The loop should respond each time it encounters a new file. There are several files in the folder I'm using, but the loop only works once. How can I fix it?

Comment: What does `GetLastError` say? If you're using VS, you can put `$err, hr` into a watch window to see without inserting an explicit error check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx) they use "C:\\MyFolder\*" * being a wildcard for all.